# Upstart - Service immediately stops after starting

Tags: upstart

Here's my `/etc/init/jobname.conf` file:

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown
respawn

script
    php /home/inersha/file.php
end script
```

When I start the service, it immediately stops:

```
$ sudo service jobname start
jobname start/running, process 16703
$ sudo service jobname status
jobname stop/waiting
```

When I run `php /home/inersha/file.php` from the command line it works fine. Also, I have the exact same setup on my local computer and that works too... it just keeps stopping on my remote server.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I checked `/var/log/upstart/JOBNAME.log` to see what was going on.

Turns out I had a relative link in my `file.php`, like this:

```
 <?php
 include '../somethin.php'
 ?>
```

I think this upstart executes this script as root `/`, so it's not able to follow the relative link. So I changed it to an absolute link and it works fine:

```
 <?php
 include '/home/inersha/folder/somethin.php'
 ?>
```

Comment: Glad you got it working!  You should consider dropping your privileges down on the script to not run it as root, if you can.  Just good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to other SAPIs [CLI SAPI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php) does **not** change the current working directory to the one the started script resides in.

A portable way would be to use the function [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) and constant [__DIR__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
<?php
require_once realpath(__DIR__ . '../somethin.php')
```

In short, when running [CLI SAPI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php) paths are relative to the directory in which the PHP process started:

```
ubuntu@h6fk4:~$ cat test.php include-me.php 
<?php
echo getcwd() . PHP_EOL;
require_once './include-me.php';
<?php
echo 'I been included!' . PHP_EOL;
ubuntu@h6fk4:~$ php test.php 
/home/ubuntu
I been included!
ubuntu@h6fk4:~$ cd /srv/
ubuntu@h6fk4:/srv$ php ~/test.php 
/srv
PHP Warning:  require_once(./include-me.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ubuntu/test.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './include-me.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ubuntu/test.php on line 3
```

Use upstart [setuid](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid) and [setgid](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setgid) stanzas to change to the user/group before running the job's process as @bc2946088 recommended.